# Easy question about computing points of infinity

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, curves, projective-space

Let us consider the curve $C$ determined by $x^2t^2 + y^2t^2 + x^2y^2 - t^4$ over $F$ ( finite field with $|F|=q$ ).
Maybe it is a stupid question but how can I compute the points at infinity? The solution has to be $[0,1,0]$ and $[0,0,1]$.

**Newest Update:** Here is the right order $[t,x,y]$ and I I see why this two points are points at infinity. My assumption is that I set the first coordinate zero to form the line at infinity and get $x^2y^2 = 0$. I get the solutions $x=1$ and $y=0 $ and $x=0$ and $y=1$. Both can't be zero because $[0,0,0]$ is not in the projetive space!

Added some context:

We have a finite field $F$. We define $A^n(F) = { (a_1,\dots,a_n) | a_i \in F }$. On  $A^{n+1}(F) -{(0,\dots,0)}$ we define an equivalence relation: $(a_0,\dots,a_n) \sim (b_0,\dots,b_n) : \Leftrightarrow \exists \alpha \in F^{*}$ with $a_i = \alpha b_i \forall i=0,\dots,n$. The equivalence classes are the points on the projective $n$-space $P^n(F)$, where $P^n(F) =(A^{n+1}(F) -{(0,\dots,0)})/ \sim$ . $H$ called hyperplane at infinity. . $P^n(F)$ is made up of two pieces, one a copy of $A^n(F)$, called the finite points, and the other a copy of $P^{n-1}(F)$, called the points at infinity.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the ordering of the homogeneous coordinates? It may be $[t,x,y]$, but that is anything but given. It would not be unreasonable to think that $x$ and $y$ are the first coordinates making it $[x,y,t]$. Which homogeneous coordinate do you set to be zero to form the line at infinity? The first? In many sources the last coordinate is the extra one. Again, the answer is suggestive in that one alternative fits. But you should tell us the conventions of your text. The question could also use other context. See [the guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Please, check out your material. It is a moral certainty that the unclear points of my previous point were explained there. Yes, I can work out the missing pieces of information by reverse engineering the answer, but in projective geometry the roles of the coordinates may change (we freely move from one affine chart to another), so for you to understand the solution, it is important that you look up those pieces from your text.

Comment: I have tried to add some context. Sorry that my question is a little bit unclear. I have added the part where the points of infinity were defined. It could be that you think that some information are still missing. Please let me know if you are need a certain information. I don't find what the ordering of the homogeneous coordinates are.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jyrki.  I think that I got the solution now. Your first comment helps me a lot. You have explained that the order has to be $[t,x,y]$ and gave me the definition for points at infinity. :)